# Excel VBA return behaving weirdly, jumps back to

Tags: debugging, vba, excel

```
Private Function GetLastSameRow(ByVal row, initialValue) As Integer
   .
   .
   .
   If (nextCell.Value = initialValue) Then
      GetLastSameRow = GetLastSameRow(row + 1, initialValue)
   End If
   MsgBox ("returning  : " & row)
   GetLastSameRow = row
End Function
```

After it finishes the if statement, the behaviour is really weird.

I ran debugger on it, and this is how it jumps:

```
1. End If                            '
2. MsgBox ("returning  : " & row)    ' row value is 3
3. GetLastSameRow = row              '
4. MsgBox ("returning  : " & row)    ' row value is 2 ????????
5. GetLastSameRow = row              '
```

So basically it wants to return the `correct`value, but then jumps back to `End if` and gets `correct-1` value from out of the blue.

Comment: The fact that it is recursive isn't the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've written a recursive function!  If you use the call stack, you'll see that the debugger is going to a different instance of your function.  The problem lies with:

GetLastSameRow = GetLastSameRow(row + 1, initialValue)

which is calling another instance of the function.

Comment: Didn't trust myself enough to know this was the right answer as soon as I saw it